# How to use custom java library in jenkins init scripts for installation?

Tags: java, jenkins

I am working on automating Jenkins installations and I'm relying on groovy scripts from $JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d .

I want to use my own java library in those scripts. So far I have discovered, that I can do that by putting my jar in $JENKINS_HOME/war/WEB-INF/lib .

The problem is that I want to make the whole process automated and so I am starting with empty $JENKINS_HOME .

```sh
java -jar jenkins.war
```

So if I copy my library before executing the command, then the command deletes it. And copying my jar after executing the command doesn't feel right.

Maybe there's a proper way of doing it? An argument to java or jenkins maybe. I have tried adding my jar to classpath, but it didn't help/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found 2 ways of using my custom jar in jenkins.

1. Put the jar inside of jenkins.war

Jenkins will add all jars in **jenkins.war/WEB-INF/lib** to classpath. So if you want to add contents of custom.jar to classpath you can simply embed it to jar. To do that you should put custom.jar to ./WEB-INF/lib and then execute the following command.

```sh
jar --update --file jenkins.war WEB-INF/lib/custom.jar
```

After that custom.jar will be in you classpath each time you run jenkins.war . **jar** utility is provided with jdk.

2. Use --commonLibFolder parameter

jenkins uses embedded jetty to work. By default jetty adds all files from **lib** directory to classpath. To specify custom directory you can use **--commonLibFolder** parameter, when jenkins is started. Here is how you can add all jars from libs directory to classpath

```sh
java -jar jenkins.war --commonLibFolder=./libs
```

Pay attention, that using **--extraLibFolder** will not work, as it adds jars to jetty classloader only.

Comment: Thats what helped me, but I'm using docker, thus I needed to add it an environment variable `JENKINS_OPTS` with the value, e.g. `JENKINS_OPTS=--commonLibFolder=/root/my_jar_folder`